# AFRAME - Can a cursor work with both gazing and clicking?

Tags: cursor, fuse, aframe, webvr

It seems like when you set fuse = "true", a cursor becomes tied to gazing and no longer reads mouse clicks. Isn't there a way to have both options, gazing and clicking both triggering the same events?

Answer (score 0):

The cursor component always reads mouse clicks, even if fuse is set: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/cursor.js#L61

If you want to point your cursor directly on the object, like a 2D web page, see https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component

Comment: no I'm just trying to allow a player to click or fuse, but only fuse is responding. Maybe it's a problem with my javascript? I have this:

link.addEventListener('click', NextEvent);

And fuse responds to it, but not clicking (unless I set fuse: "false"). Do I need an additional event listener or a different one?

Comment: further illustrative of this, check out https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/

If fuse is true, the links only bring you to new pictures while gazing (not clicking).

If fuse is false, the links only bring you to new pictures while clicking. 

Interestingly, the animations on the links respond in both scenarios (scale resize), just not the action of switching to new panoramas.

Comment: Hmm, you could always listen to `document.querySelector('a-scene canvas').addEventListener('click')` as a workaround.

Comment: you mean like `document.querySelector('a-scene canvas').addEventListener('click', function)` ? Still doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes cursor can work with both gazing and clicking.
The following code can be written fir clicking,

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-scene>
```

& then the camera entity contain within the a-scene should have cursor entity which triggers fuse, like

```
<a-cursor geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03" material="color: black; shader: flat"></a-cursor>
```

Ofcourse there will be fusing parameter added in it.